# Flutter pageview navigate

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I use `pageController.jumptopage(0)` method on button in *Page3.dart* ? Is it possible? Full example code:

**main.dart file**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_app/page1.dart';
import 'package:test_app/page2.dart';
import 'package:test_app/page3.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late PageController pageController;
  int selectedPage = 0;
  final List<Widget> pagesList = [const Page1(), const Page2(), const Page3()];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        children: pagesList,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() => selectedPage = index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Page3.dart file**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Button'),
          onPressed: () {
            // pageController.jumptopage(0); <<< use this
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve specifically on button click on page3 ?

Comment: To switch to page 0 when the button is pressed, using ```pageController.jumptopage(0);```